# calculate total id in data with particular condition

Tags: php, mysql

I want to calculate total no. of students present in a particular class. 
Every class have unique id **for Ex: Nursery A has id: 1**

Current Situation :

If Teacher Logged in session... in teacher and students table there is a column with **class_id** which contains same **id = 1**.

Then that particular teacher which assigned class_id = 1 than. he/she can view only that particular class id list.

---

and if other teacher has assigned other class_id than he/she won't able to see other class_id list.

---

```
<?php 

require_once "../conf/config.php";
$sql="SELECT count(id) AS total FROM students join staff on students.class_id=staff.class_id where class_id=staff.class_id";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$value=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$num_row=$value['total'];
echo "<b>" .$num_row. "</b>";

?>
```

i am not able to get the proper sol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here most probably is that both the students and staff table has a column named `id`.

You should clarify what `id` you want to count in the SQL statement.

Try replacing the `count(id)` with `count(students.id)` as well as always indicating the parent table and it should fix your results. The where clause here is obsolete as we have the condition in the join.

```
$sql="SELECT count(students.id) AS total FROM students join staff on students.class_id=staff.class_id";
```

This will give you the total number of students associated with a class.

Moreover you may want to use `INNER JOIN` instead of join. This will help with the performance, though I do not know what exactly you want the data for.

In order to check a particular class, you should put a parameter indicating the actual class id you want to count.

```
$sql="SELECT count(students.id) AS total FROM students join staff on students.class_id=staff.class_id where students.class_id=ENTER_CLASS_ID_HERE";
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using inner join then you don't need to use where condition in your query as inner join gives only those records which are present in both tables according to on condition,
[See here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) for the reference,
you can try this :

```
SELECT count(st.id) AS total 
FROM students st 
INNER JOIN staff s on st.class_id=s.class_id
```